# Changing the order of the folders' previews in Windows 10 taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'd like to know if there is a way to change the order of the folders' previews in Windows 10 taskbar. E.g. the preview of the folder "Immagini" should be the first one, the preview of the folder "Dizionario" the second one.

[image]

The above example is a simple case, so I could close the windows and reopen them in the desired order; my goal is to learn how to change the order of the previews because sometimes I open many folders.

Comment: Yeah thats not how that works, try another tactic like Snapping https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241